# memory with multiple uses of "new File"

Tags: java, memory-management, new-operator

I am trying to write a function that will take a string representation of a project name and attempt to create a folder with a matching name. If such a folder already exists, I want to create a folder with the same name followed by "-1", or if the "-1" version already exists, it will create a "-2" version instead.

For example, if the project name is CandyMachine then the folder would be called CandyMachine. If a folder by that name already exists, it would attempt to create a folder named CandyMachine-1. If CandyMachine-1 already exists, then it will attempt to create a folder named CandyMachine-2, etc.

Here is the code that I have implemented so far:

```
private static String getOutputPath(String projName){
    String newPath = "Projects" + File.separator + projName;


    File pathFile = new File(newPath);

    if(pathFile.exists()){
        int i = 1;
        while(pathFile.exists()){
            pathFile = new File(newPath + "-" + i);
            i++;
        }

        newPath += "-" + Integer.toString(i);
        newPath += File.separator + "src";
        return newPath;
    }
    else
        return newPath;
}
```

My question regarding the above code is if I can potentially cause a memory leak by repeatedly creating new File objects within the while loop? If that is the case, how can I avoid it? As far as I know I am unable to change the path of an already-existing File object. Is there a better way to check what I am trying to check?

Comment: There will be **no** memory leak or insufficient memory situation.

Comment: Memory leak, no. It could be that File is using OS resources though. Not sure about that myself.

Comment: The moment you execute your "`new File()`" statement, your old `File` object becomes dereferenced and subject to Garbage Collection.  You  will be limited just by your OS file system constrains.

Comment: Uh, do you still use Java 6 or less? If no, consider using `Path` instead

Comment: @Radiodef "It could be that File is using OS resources though" -- no it won't. As the javadoc mention, a `File` is an abstract path name. But then again, if you use Java 7 or better, you should ditch `File` and use `Path` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> My question regarding the above code is if I can potentially cause a memory leak by repeatedly creating new File objects within the while loop?

No. As long as a reference falls out of scope, it is eligible for garbage collection. Therefore, all the `File` objects you create will eventually be garbage collected.

Now, there is another problem which is more fundamental in 2014: don't use `File` anymore, use `Path`. Here is how you would write your code using the newer, and by far better, file API:

```
private static final Path PROJECT_DIR = Paths.get("Projects");

// ...

private static String getOutputPath(final String projName)
{
    Path ret = PROJECT_DIR.resolve(projName);
    int index = 1;

    while (Files.exists(ret))
        ret = PROJECT_DIR.resolve(projName + '-' + index++);

    return ret.toString();
}
```

Of course, this code could be vastly improved; for instance, only the existence of the path is checked, not whether the path is actually a directory, a regular file or even a symlink (yes, the new API can detect that; `File` cannot).

Answer (score -1):

Wait a minute, When the input argument is only one `String` representing a `Project Name` why do you require a `while loop`
Instead of a `while loop` iterating over all the files just to find if a token is taken or not, how about breaking this into two step wherein in first step you have a `FileNameFilter` which lists all the files starting with the `Project Name` followed by processing the file names to create the appropriate directory.

```
File dir = new File("Projects" + File.separator + projName);
String[] foundFiles = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.startsWith(projName);
}
});

for (String filename : foundFiles) {
   // Process filename by finding the maximum token after project name and creating the directory based on the last found token +1
}
```

Comment: Your "answer" should've been a comment.

Comment: The OP actually explains what the loop is for.

Comment: I want it to iterate until a new number is found. So, if there are 4 projects with the name "CandyMachine" then it will iterate until it finds that "CandyMachine-4" is not taken, and will return that as the correct path.

Comment: @Jdm2010: Interesting, Didn't catch that on initial look.